# Fetching attachments from incoming emails using mailgun with PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailgun

I'm using mailgun to parse incoming emails. mailgun sends the parsed emails to a URL (https://example.com/email).

I'm able to fetch the from, to, subject, body etc. However I'm not able to fetch the attachments.

Below is my code and it returns a null value.

```
$file = addslashes(file_get_contents($this->input->post('attachment-1'))['name']);

$result = $this->tickets_model->saving_files($file);
```

Please help me out.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've gotten this to work is to use the CI upload library to first upload the file and then parse it.

```
$config['file_name']  = 'filename';
$config['upload_path'] = '/upload/path';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('attachment-1')) {
  // fail
} else {
  // success
}
```